# Async function returning a new Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have the following scenario, which I'm trying to understand

```
const myPromise = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('done');
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

I'm aware that all async functions are returning a Promise.

But what will actually happen under the hood when i call this function?

```
await myPromise();
```

I **know that the `async` keyword, is not needed in this case**, but either using it, or not,  the result is 1 pending promise. What is happening to the second promise? Shouldn't return a promise, wrapped in a promise? In which way, is this handled?

Comment: If the function returns a Promise, no new promise will be created; there's just one.

Comment: Simple as that! Thanks @Pointy